# JS FormData sends file as application/ocet-stream, how to set it as multipart/form-data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As in the title, I'm trying to upload file to Spring Rest Controller using:

```
handleOnChange() {
    let inputFile = document.getElementById("file-input");
    this.file.file = inputFile.files[0];
    this.file.filename = inputFile.value;
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="file-input">
                <input id="file-input" type="file"
                    onChange={(event) => this.handleOnChange()} />
        </div>
    );
}

upload() {
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", this.data.file.file, "/D:/temp/test2.xlf");
formData.append("request", JSON.stringify(request));

let reqOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
}

fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8081/multi-mt-evaluation/report', reqOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

But when fetch is called the file is sent as application/octet-stream, is there a simple, or more complicated way to set it as multipart/form-data?

Comment: You can set it in your fetch headers. Please share that part of your code

Comment: I'm not setting fetch headers, and it's not problem with the headers, the problem is with file that I'm appending, because it's set as application/octet-stream, and RestController returns that this content-type is not supported. But to be clear: request header Content-Type is set to: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------14633021267396739684124373734

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the content type by adding it to your request headers:

```
let reqOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
}
```

Comment: This doesn't set the boundary needed in header, which is done automatically by browser.